# Dimension error in Denoising AutoEncoder model Dimensions must be equal, but are 9252 and 129 for with input shapes: [?,9252,32], [?,129,32]

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to build an Autoencoder model using TensorFlow. The input data shape: `(339, 129, 32)`
The model architecture is as follows:

```py
input_data = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=train_sample.shape[1:])

masking = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=-100.0)(input_data)

conv = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128, 3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(3),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D(2),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
])
fc = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32),
])
conv_out = conv(masking)
fc_out = fc(conv_out)

defc = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(576),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU()
])

dconv = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1024, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1DTranspose(576, kernel_size=3, dilation_rate=2),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1DTranspose(384, kernel_size=4, strides=3, padding='same'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1DTranspose(32, kernel_size=3, strides=3),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation("sigmoid")
])


defc_out = defc(fc_out)
dconv_out = dconv(defc_out)
```

But getting the following error:

`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 9252 and 129 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_6/sequential_21/activation_3/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,9252,32], [?,129,32].`

I am looking forward for your helpin fixing the model architecture.

I tried to play around with the model Architure, unfortunately nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your model architecture, we can find your shapes of each variable:

```
conv_out: (None, 21, 16)
fc_out: (None, 32)
defc_out: (None, 1024)
dconv_out: (None, 9252, 32)
```

The error message indicates that you are using the `mean_squared_error`, which implies that the input shape should match the output shape.

However, you have specified the input shape as `(None, 129, 32)`, while the output shape is `(None, 9252, 32)`, which clearly differs.

You can refer some github examples about denosing autoencoder: https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/generative/autoencoder.ipynb